# How to bypass a reference to an outer table in subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I've been dealing with these two tables:

**Document**

```
id    company_id    etc
=======================
1     2             x
2     2             x
```

**Version**

```
id    document_id   version    date_created    date_issued   date_accepted
==========================================================================
1     1             1          2013-04-29      2013-04-30    NULL
2     2             1          2013-05-01      NULL          NULL
3     1             2          2013-05-01      2013-05-01    2013-05-03
```

There's a page where I want to list all documents with their attributes.
And I would like to add a single have status from each document.
The status can be derived from the most present date that corresponding `Version`s have.
It is possible that an older version is being accepted.

The query result I am looking for is like this:

```
id    company_id    etc   status
==================================
1     2             x     accepted
2     2             x     created
```

I started out by making a query which combines all dates and add a status next to it.
It works as expected and when I add the document_id things look alright.

```
SELECT `status`
FROM (
    SELECT max(date_created) as `date`,'created' as `status` FROM version WHERE document_id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT max(date_issued),'issued' FROM version WHERE document_id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT max(date_accepted),'accepted' FROM version WHERE document_id = 1
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as maxi
```

When I try to incorporate this query as a subquery, I can't make it work.

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT `status` FROM (
    SELECT max(date_created) as `date`,'created' as `status`FROM version WHERE document_id = document.id
    UNION
    SELECT max(date_issued),'issued' FROM version WHERE document_id = document.id
    UNION
    SELECT max(date_accepted),'accepted' FROM version WHERE document_id = document.id
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) as maxi
) as `status`
FROM `document`
```

This will get me the error `Unknown column 'document.id' in 'where clause'`. So I've read around at SO and figured it simply can't reach the value `offer.id` since it's a subquery in a subquery. So I tried to take another approach and get all the statuses at once, to avoid the `WHERE` statement, and JOIN them. I ended up with the next query.

```
SELECT MAX(`date`),`status`, document_id
FROM (
    SELECT datetime_created as `date`, 'created' as `status`,document_id FROM `version`
    UNION
    SELECT datetime_issued, 'issued',document_id FROM `version`
    UNION
    SELECT datetime_accepted, 'accepted',document_id FROM `version`
) as dates
GROUP BY offer_id
```

No error this time but I realized that the `status` couldn't be the correct one since it got lost during the `GROUP BY`. I've tried combinations of the two but both flaws keep hindering me. Could any one suggest how to do this in a single query without changing my database? (I know that saving the dates in a separate table would simply things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you normalise your table designs to move the status / dates onto a different table from the Versions?

If no possibly something like this:-

```
SELECT Document.id, Document.company_id, Document.etc, CASE WHEN Sub1.status = 3 THEN 'accepted' WHEN Sub1.status = 2 THEN 'issued' WHEN Sub1.status = 1 THEN 'created' ELSE NULL END AS status
FROM Document
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT document_id, MAX(CASE WHEN date_accepted IS NOT NULL THEN 3 WHEN date_issued IS NOT NULL THEN 2 WHEN date_created IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS status 
    FROM Version
    GROUP BY document_id
) Sub1
ON Document.id = Sub1.document_id
```

The subselect gets the highest status for any document from the version table. Each possible versions highest status is returned as a number, and by grouping that on the document id it will get the highest status of any version. This is joined back against the Document table and the number for the version number converted into the text description.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but you can do it like this (you might need to tweak the details)

It is basically looking at it from a completely different angle.

```
 select
    d.*,
    (CASE GREATEST(ifnull(v.date_created, 0), ifnull(v.date_issued,0), ifnull(v.date_accepted,0) ) 
      WHEN null THEN 'unknown'
      WHEN v.date_accepted THEN 'accepted'
      WHEN v.date_issued THEN 'issued'
      WHEN v.date_created THEN 'created'
      END) as status 
from document d
left join version v on 
    v.document_id = d.document_id and 
    not exists (select 1 from (select * from version) x where x.document_id = v.document_id and x.id <> v.id and x.version > v.version)
```

Comment: greatest selects the largest of the values. i did not assume the dates are always in order. if they are always in rder you can just be done with some checks to see if it is null

Comment: According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest GREATEST returns NULL if any argument is NULL. Which is in all cases when there isn't an accepted version of a document

Comment: @tomas, totally true, i changed it.

Comment: It looks to me that the NOT EXISTS condition tries to get the latest version out of two. But there could be more versions and it is possible that a prior version will be accepted.

Comment: the not extsts will always take the latest one. it checks if there are any version records with a higher version number. so it will always use the latest version record

Comment: I have tested it now with fiddle, just check. it works.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8003/5

Answer (score 0):

```
select Doc.document_id,Doc.company_id,Doc.etc,f.status
from Document Doc
inner join 
    (select Ver.document_id,
    case when Ver.date_accepted is not null then 'Accepted'
    when Ver.date_issued is not null then 'Issued'
    when Ver.date_created is not null then 'Created'
    end as status
from version Ver
inner join (
                select document_id,MAX(version) VersionId
                from version
                group by document_id
            )t on t.document_id=Ver.document_id 
where t.VersionId=Ver.version
)f on Doc.document_id=f.document_id
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8003/1)**

Comment: Your starting point, the latest version, doesn't apply to my situation. Any version can be accepted. Acceptance will be final event.

Comment: Ok. Let me see, how can i help you.